# C# get fibonacci IEnumerable<int> with recursion.. I want it to return all the numbers, not only the last one

Tags: c#

```
static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciByLength(int length)
    {
        if (length <= 1)
            yield return 1;
        else
            yield return FibonacciByLength(length - 1).Last() + 
         FibonacciByLength(length - 2).Last();
    }
```

This code returns only last value, but I want it to return all of them..

Comment: You may consider of using `List`. Then you could simply `Add` your Fibonacci number

Comment: Fibonacci is like the textbook example of an algorithm that is just awful to use naive recursion on.  You should be using an iterative approach to solving this problem.  It's be linear, rather than exponential, complexity, and the code will be plenty simple.

Comment: Thank you Ian for your answer, will keep it in mind

Comment: In addition, `IEnumerable` does not lend itself to recursion very well. You have to use `foreach` on every recursive call, which creates a new Enumerator object every time. (It is called an **iterator** after all. 'iterator' = 'iterative')

Comment: I will search some stuff about iterator, it is new for me, but very interesting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not restricted by the parameters that you pass into your method, I would suggest the following

```
    static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciByLength(int maxValues, int valuesCalculatedSoFar = 0, int previousValue1 = 0, int previousValue2 = 0)
    {
        int nextValue;

        if (valuesCalculatedSoFar < 2)
        {
            nextValue = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            nextValue = previousValue1 + previousValue2;
        }

        yield return nextValue;

        valuesCalculatedSoFar++;

        if (valuesCalculatedSoFar < maxValues)
        {
            foreach(var value in FibonacciByLength(maxValues, valuesCalculatedSoFar, previousValue2, nextValue))
            {
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which you would call using

```
    var values = FibonacciByLength(10).ToList();
```

The reason for this is you avoid unnecessary calls. Using this method, if you want to calculate the first 10 values of the Fibonacci sequence, it would only call FibonacciByLength 10 times. In each call to FibonacciByLength you pass in the values needed to calculate the next value so you don't have to recalculate it.

Using the method suggested by Arturo, you would call the method 2089 times. This is because there's multiple calls like FibonacciByLength(length - 1).Last(), which requires recalculating the entire sequence up to the length passed in just to get the last value. If you can only pass in the length value then you don't have any other option and you have to live with the exponential number of calls that will need to be made.

Comment: It works awesome. I also was thinking about it, but so its new for me, and It's a bit hard to understand, will work more on it, and will try to  write code that calculates fibonacci numbers, which are lower than int maxValue

Comment: Wouldn't be hard to modify to return values up to a limit. You would remove all uses of valuesCalcualtedSoFar and you could rename maxValues to maxValue. Then in the if statement near the end you would just need to check if nextValue < maxValue. This would make the recursion stop once nextValue is greater than or equal to maxValue.

Comment: I did exactly the same, there are little details that aren't clear yet,, but I think I need just more practice. Thanks a lot again, this was my first question and I'm very glad for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If `length` is greater than `1` you need to `yield return` every number in `FibonacciByLength(length - 1)`:

```
static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciByLength(int length)
{
    if (length == 1) yield return 1;
    else if (length == 2)
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var fib in FibonacciByLength(length - 1))
            yield return fib;

        yield return FibonacciByLength(length - 1).Last() + FibonacciByLength(length - 2).Last();
    }
}
```

But I recommend you not to use recursion to avoid redundant calculations:

```
static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciByLength(int length)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        int c = a + b;

        a = b;
        b = c;

        yield return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: First solution is using recursion and enumerables

Comment: The 2nd method can be simplified to: `static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciByLength(int length) {
  int a = 1, b = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   int c = a + b;
   a = b;
   b = c;
   yield return c;
  }
 }`